# Jython & Mysql - what is the current practice for connection?

Tags: mysql, jython

Just trying jython for the first time, because something came up at work that would fit for this perfect for it.  I assume jython can make mysql jdbc connection using the mysql jdbc driver.  After googling and reading, however I am having problems and it seems jython specific and probably simple.
so i do jython:

```
Jython 2.5.1 (Release_2_5_1:6813, Sep 26 2009, 13:47:54) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Apple Inc.)] on java1.6.0_17
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/JYTHONPATH/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar', '/WorkArea/Apps/jython/jython2.5.1/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/', '/WorkArea/Apps/jython/jython2.5.1/Lib/site-packages']
>>>
```

***code i'm running***

```
from java.lang import *
from java.sql import *
driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Class.forName(driverName)
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=jgreenaw&password="
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
stmt = con.createStatement()
```

***output***

```
riux:Desktop$ jython pymysql.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymysql.py", line 7, in <module>
    Class.forName(driverName)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

any advice?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that "/JYTHONPATH/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar" exists?

Comment: yes:
riuxjg:JYTHONPATH$ ls
mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar

Comment: assuming that its the right path, in theory that should work correct?

Comment: It should work (at least I can't find anything wrong in your code). Try to `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` - that should tell you if the JAR was loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have rights to read that .jar? In your code try to open it as file. Also check if this file is valid `jar` archive that contains `com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.class`.

While I use PostgreSQL on Windows I can check it with:

```
import zipfile

def test_jar(jar_file, class_name):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'r')
    cn = class_name.replace('.', '/') + '.class'
    zi = zf.getinfo(cn)
    print('%s: %s [b] -> %s [b]' % (zi.filename, zi.file_size, zi.compress_size))

test_jar('c:/jars/postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar', 'org.postgresql.Driver')
```

Comment: yes, i do, its in my home folder, and its the same jar i use for other java programs. Previously I did a jar -tvf mysql.jar | grep Driver and it found it.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: What will Jython do if you delete/rename .jar file? Can you use any OS tool to check what files Jython try to open?

Answer (score 2):

Add mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar to the CLASSPATH environment variable, not just the JYTHONPATH environment variable.